# I am to ask to show that $P\cap (P\cap Q )^{c} = P\cap Q^{c}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[As a reference, here's a picture for P ∩ Q'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBGWt.png)

[image: 1]

Comment: What did your picture teach you?  Can you locate the left side on the picture?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{align}P\cap (P\cap Q )^{c} &=P\cap( P^c\cup Q^{c})\\&=(P\cap P^c)\cup (P\cap Q^{c})\\&=(P\cap Q^{c})\end{align}$

since $P\cap P^c=\phi$.